# How can i count number of digits in tetrated numbers?

Tags: decimal-expansion, tetration

As you read in the title, I need a technique for counting number of digits in [tetrated numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

For example:

${3^{(3)}}^3 = 7625597484987 $(13 digits)

${7^{(7)}}^7 = $How many digits (approximately)?

${{11}^{(11)}}^{11} $= How many digits (approximately)?

Is there any technique for calculation?

Comment: Log to the base 10?

Comment: The number of digits has roughly $x\log x$ digits. For $x=3$, for instance, the number of digits ($13$) has $2$ digits, and $3\log3\approx 1.4$.

Comment: We can expect that the number of digits in the number of digits in $7^{7^7}$ to be roughly $6$. (That is, $7^{7^7}$ has $N$ digits, where $N$ is probably a six-digit number.)

Comment: For completeness: $7^{7^7}$ has $695975$ digits, while $11^{11^11}$ has $297121486765$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

The number of digits of $n$ is $\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor+1$  If we ignore the floor and the $+1$, we get $\log_{10}7^{7^7}=7^7 \log 7\approx 695974$ as shown by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E7*log%2810%2C7%29).  This is fine for three layer tetrations, but is inadequate for taller ones.  For example, if you ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%5E7%5E7*log%2810%2C7%29) for $7^{7^7}\log_{10}7$ you get back $10^{10^{5.842593328962333}}$ which is still in tetrated form.  Basically each log only takes one layer off the stack.